# PyQt4: why do we need to pass class name in call to super()

Tags: python, class, inheritance, pyqt4

as in the following code `super(MdiChild, self).__init__()` we are passing mdichild in the super function.please explain me why and why `.__init__()` is used.

```
class MdiChild(QtGui.QTextEdit):
   sequenceNumber = 1

   def __init__(self):
      super(MdiChild, self).__init__()
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In python3.3+ you *don't* need to pass the class name explicitly, you can just do:

```
super().__init__()
```

Now, note that `super` does **not** call the constructor. It simply provides an object where you can access the attributes of the given instance as if it was an instance of the parent class. For example you could call `setText`:

```
super().setText('Hello')  # calls QLineEdit.setText
```

In python<3.3 `super` is a normal function. It doesn't have anything special. This means that it does *not* know from which class it was called, and hence it cannot now how to find the parent class without passing the arguments explicitly. Also you may want to do things like:

```
super(QLineEdit, self).__init__()
```

Which would call `QLineEdit`'s parent class `__init__()` (i.e. the grand-parent `__init__()` function).

From python3.3 a "hack" was added so that the call to `super` without arguments is equivalent to calling `super(CurrentClass, self)`. This required some changes in the compiler.

---

Here's a simple example of how `super` works:

```
In [1]: class MyBase(object):
   ...:     def __init__(self):
   ...:         print('MyBase.__init__() called')

In [2]: class MyChild(MyBase):
   ...:     def __init__(self):
   ...:         print('MyChild.__init__() called')
   ...:         super().__init__() # MyBase.__init__
   ...:         

In [3]: class MyGrandChild(MyChild):
   ...:     def __init__(self):
   ...:         print('MyGrandChild.__init__() called')
   ...:         super().__init__()  # MyChild.__init__
   ...:         print('Between super calls')
   ...:         super(MyChild, self).__init__()  # MyBase.__init__
   ...:         super(MyBase, self).__init__() # object.__init__ (does nothing)

In [4]: MyGrandChild()
MyGrandChild.__init__() called
MyChild.__init__() called
MyBase.__init__() called
Between super calls
MyBase.__init__() called
```

In python<3.3 where you cannot omit the class name every call to `super()` without arguments must be replaced with:

```
super(NameOfCurrentClass, self)
```

For example:

```
In [7]: class MyBase(object):
   ...:     def __init__(self):
   ...:         print('MyBase.__init__() called')

In [8]: class MyChild(MyBase):
   ...:     def __init__(self):
   ...:         print('MyChild.__init__() called')
   ...:         super(MyChild, self).__init__()

In [9]: class MyGrandChild(MyChild):
   ...:     def __init__(self):
   ...:         print('MyGrandChild.__init__() called')
   ...:         super(MyGrandChild, self).__init__()
   ...:         print('Between super calls')
   ...:         super(MyChild, self).__init__()
   ...:         super(MyBase, self).__init__()

In [10]: MyGrandChild()
MyGrandChild.__init__() called
MyChild.__init__() called
MyBase.__init__() called
Between super calls
MyBase.__init__() called
```

The expression `super(A, instance)` means: take a proxy to object `instance` where I can access the methods of `A`'s *parent*. The "parent" is defined by the [MRO](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/):

```
In [12]: MyGrandChild.__mro__
Out[12]: (__main__.MyGrandChild, __main__.MyChild, __main__.MyBase, builtins.object)
```

In the case of single inheritance is simply the name of class in the hierarchy up to `object`, but with multiple inheritance the tree is linearized so if class `A` so which method is called becomes more complicated to guess.

Comment: Two Questions :
Q1: `super().setText('Hello')  # calls QLineEdit.setText`. Isn't `QLineEdit` current class, from which we are calling `super`? Then `setText()` should be a method of the parent class as i can guess!    
Q2: Which would call QLineEdit's parent class __init__() (i.e. the grand-parent __init__() function). How grand parent? I think it should be parent or i do not understand what you are saying?

Comment: @rock You should probably read: [How does `super()` work with multiple inheritance?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277367/how-does-pythons-super-work-with-multiple-inheritance). However I'll now add a simple example that might give you some understanding on which method will `super` call.

Answer (score 0):

Consider `C` inherits from `B` and `B` inherits from `A` and you create an object `foo` of type `C`.

`foo.__init__()` is `C.__init__()`, which calls `B.__init__`. But, as the object is of type `C`, if `B.__init__` did not specify it wants to call `B`'s parent `__init__` (ie. `A.__init__`), it would be calling itself (ie. `B.__init__`), as `B` is the parent class of the object.

Not sure if I am clear here, I hope that helps.

Comment: Sorry, but that is confusing!